# I can't send data through serial port using Visual Studio 2017 (C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, serial-communication

I try to make a windows application and I have a problem with C# serial communication. I've read a lot of articles about it and watched a lot of youtube tutorials, but the communication still doesn't work. I'm using Visual Studio 2017(community) on Windows 8.1 system. The problem is, that my code can open the serial port and it can close it but when I try to send data between them, nothing happens. For testing I used TeraTerm and sent out some bytes with it to my microcontroller and the micorC could receive that. But with my code, as I said, nothing happens. My code is:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.IO.Ports;

 namespace Cucc
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        byte[] d = new byte[1] { 0x0d };
        byte[] a = new byte[1] { 0x0a };

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1 = new SerialPort();
            serialPort1.PortName = "COM4"; 
            serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
            serialPort1.DataBits = 8;
            serialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One;
            serialPort1.Parity = Parity.None;
            serialPort1.Open();


        } 

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Try to send some stuff here
            serialPort1.WriteLine("1");
            serialPort1.Write(a, 0, 1);
            serialPort1.Write(d, 0, 1);
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             serialPort1.Close();
        }
    }
 }
```

My microcontroller always connects to the COM4 port (everytime I connect it, I check the port). Does anyone have any idea, why can't I send data out? I tried with Microsoft Visual C# 2008 Express Edition too, but the code didn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any hardware/software flow control settings that are different?

Comment: <Dummy guy answers> To be honest, I don't really know which flow control settings do you mean. I just made sure that I use the 1 start - 8 data - no parity - 1 stop bit frame in both situation with 9600 baud rate. <\Dummy guy answers> I forgot to mention some additional infos: Yesterday evening I tried to run the code on one of my friends computer and (what a surprise) it didn't work. That computer has Windows 10 system. BUT in my workplace I wrote earlier a c# code with the same commands and there it works! That computer has Windows 7 and I used Visual C# 2008 or 2010 Express.